# Issue with Java string search pattern ( contains / matches)

Tags: java, string

I have one string which contains a couple of attribute values. While verifying whether the string contains specific attribute values or not by using some simple regex, the matches function is always returning false value.

Now I need the behavior like,

1. If String contains `\"import\" :` Then I need `isExportSet` to be
   set as true.
2. If String contains `\"path\" : true` Then I need
   `isPathSet` to be set to true.

I tried as shown below, but it did not work for me:

```
public class DriverClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\"import\" : \"static\",\"path\" : true";
        boolean isExportSet = str.matches("\\*+export\\*+");
        boolean isPathSet = str.matches("\\*+multipath\\s+:\\s+true");

        System.out.println("Export " + isExportSet);
        System.out.println("Path  " + isPathSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current behavior and what do you want? If something is wrong with the regexp it is easier to help if you provide examples that should match and examples that shouldn't match.

Comment: boolean isExportSet = str.matches(".*export.*");
        boolean isPathSet = str.matches(".*path.*");

Is this what you want?

Comment: Updated the question with my requirement

Comment: This seems to be some part of JSON data. Why not simply use a JSON parser and analyze the result - which might be much cleaner than the regex approach?

Comment: I would ratter implement a reader and link it to a validation implementation using something like a `Map<String, Validator>`. This would be cleaner than having a bunch of regex pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if the following code fulfill the problem deifinition.

```
static String str = "\"import\" : \"static\",\"path\" : true";

static void test(String str) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] parts = str.split("(:|,)");
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i+=2) {
        map.put(getUnquotedStr(parts[i]), getUnquotedStr(parts[i+1]));
    }
    System.out.println(map.size() + " entries: " + map); // 2 entries: {path=true, import=static}
    boolean isExportSet = "".equals(map.get("import"));
    boolean isPathSet = "true".equals(map.get("path"));
    System.out.println(isExportSet + " - " + isPathSet);
}

private static String getUnquotedStr(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\"", "").trim();
}
```

will print as follows on the console:

- 2 entries: {path=true, import=static}
- false - true

Answer (score 0):

Testing the string for containing `\"import\"` is just checking if the string contains `"import"`. In your regular expression you need to disregard the `\` check because this is an escape character for Java to be able to handle the double quotes inside a string, without ending the string definition. You will, however, need to escape those characters in your regex as well.

For `"import"` the regex becomes `str.matches(\"import\")`. Analogous for the `"path"` string.

I found this a handy tool to check regex's: [Free Formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `str.contains("valueToSerach")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\"import\"
\"(path|multipath)\"
```

And please never connect a * with another quantity indicator that leads to errors.

And since you want to check the " hard, you have to include them in your expression.